# python-pandas: .to_csv() not creating the *.csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, read.csv

(delete after answered - I can't find a similar issue in SO database but feel the problem is something silly)

Edit: It is created, but only shows through windows explorer (Pycharm doesn't update the new file in the cwd).

The *.csv file isn't showing up in the working directory. I'm using Pycharm and have installed the pandas package and have the "ExcelReader" plugin.

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("2018_Central_Park_Squirrel_Census_-_Squirrel_Data.csv")
gray = sum(data["Primary Fur Color"] == "Gray")
red = sum(data["Primary Fur Color"] == "Cinnamon")
black = sum(data["Primary Fur Color"] == "Black")
squirrel_dict = {
    "Color": ["Gray", "Red", "Black"],
    "Population": [gray, red, black],
}
squirrels_by_color = pandas.DataFrame(squirrel_dict)
print(squirrels_by_color)

#    Color  Population
# 0   Gray        2473
# 1    Red         392
# 2  Black         103

squirrels_by_color.to_csv("squirrels_by_color.csv")
# not creating the *.csv file ????????
# I've installed pandas and "ExcelReader" plugin...
```

In the tutorial video the file will appear in the working directory after using the *.to_csv() command and launching the script. I'm 90% sure my code is correct (the dataframe looks good), yet it doesn't create the file.

Comment: If you don't get error - it creates the csv, but not where you think it should be located. Use a absolute path, to test. Right now it will be in current working directory. What do you call `working directory`? Note, this may not be the directory where the script is located.

Comment: Everything is in the same folder as the main.py file.  In Pycharm, A window shows "main.py", "theOriginalCSVFile.csv"... but the new file is never created and put into that same folder. Possibly a security feature not allowing the file to be created?     Edit: Ahh..  It does create the file if you look in through windows explorer. It just doesn't update the new file in the directory in Pycharm. Is there a setting for that?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say exactly what the issue is without knowing more info. But if you run (in a jupyter cell):

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

It will print your current working directory (cwd). This is where your file would be saving, since you have specified a relative path that says to save the file in your cwd. If you are not in a jupyter notebook, and are running your python file in the terminal, the file will save at the specified location when you run `pwd` in the terminal (or `cd` if you are on windows). Your code does look good to me also, and even if `squirrels_by_color` was an empty `df`, it would still save an empty `.csv` in your current working directory.